# Argument Error while trying to filter by date.today() in sqlachemy python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

## sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError when trying to filter by today'date

able to print the date out date.today() but when I use it with  sqlalchemy its throwing attribute error telling a Constraint is expected

### Code I Tried

```
def daily_Fitness() :
    result = Fitness.query.filter_by ( date.today () )

    for result in result :
        result.append ( {"Yoga" : Fitness.activity_type_1 , "Jogging" : Fitness.activity_type_2 ,
                         "Walking" : Fitness.activity_type_2 ,
                         "time" : Fitness.fitness_time ,
                         "comments" : Fitness.comments

                         } )
    return result
```

### Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\siveg\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 124, in _init_items
    spwd = item._set_parent_with_dispatch
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/siveg/gitProject/python-project-template/python-project-template/application/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    class Food(db.Model) :
  File "C:/Users/siveg/gitProject/python-project-template/python-project-template/application/models.py", line 16, in Food
    date=db.Column (date.today(), unique=True , nullable=False )
  File "C:\Users\siveg\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1636, in __init__
    self._init_items(*args)
  File "C:\Users\siveg\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 126, in _init_items
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\siveg\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected, got datetime.date(2021, 7, 27)
```

### Code Explanation

suppose to fetch the data for that particular table for current date

### Expected Output

```
Able to successfully fetch the data entered from the table as specified
{"Yoga" : Fitness.activity_type_1 , "Jogging" : Fitness.activity_type_2 ,
                         "Walking" : Fitness.activity_type_2 ,
                         "time" : Fitness.fitness_time ,
                         "comments" : Fitness.comments}
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter_by` expects keyword arguments whose keyword is a column name and whole value is to filter with.

So in this case if you had a table like:

```py
from datetime import date
class FitnessRoutine(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'fitness_routines'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
   scheduled_on = Column(Date, default=date.today)
```

You would pass `filter_by` the name of the column `scheduled_on`:

```py
routines_for_today = FitnessRoutine.query.filter_by(scheduled_on=date.today())
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter_by